# Access Form cant update or add records

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010

I am currently creating a Form on access however when I go into form view I am unable to update any of the current records or add new records would anyone have any idea why I cant edit or update my records? or how I go about fixing this?

My Form is currently linked to a query, and incase it matters I also have inlcuded a search function in my form.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks 
Paula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the query you use is not updateable. There are a lot of limitations for updateable queries design, for instance you cannot use aggregaing in query, joins should have unique keys etc. Try to redesign your query. As a workaround you can copy the data from your query to temporary table, edit the data in this table and then copy data back to main table(s)

Comment: Thankyou very much ive just one other question... I have created this in a table instead but I also have a ComboBox on my form how do I make sure it clears in between each record? so it doesnt update all my records to the same thing?

Comment: No, combobox for bound field  updates only current record. If control with combobox is unbound, you will see the same value in all rows. Just use bound controls.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is probably not updateable. You can check this by simply opening the query directly, and trying to edit/add data.

The most common reason is a JOIN on non-indexed columns.

For more reasons see: [Dealing with Non-Updateable Microsoft Access Queries](http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html)
or [Allen Browne: Why is my query read-only?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)

Comment: thank you for this I tried to update my query and it didnt let me so swapped to a table